# RollupJs with bootstrap-sass

Tags: bootstrap-sass, rollupjs

I’ve started to play around with rollupjs and can’t seem to get it working with bootstrap-sass.

I'm getting the error when bundling -

> (sass plugin) File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
>   Parent style sheet: stdin

Snippets of my code below.

I've included a `rollup-plugin-sass` in my `rollup.config.js`.

```
// index.js
import './jquery-global.js'
import 'bootstrap-sass'
import './style.scss'


// jquery-global.js
import jquery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jquery

// style.scss
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
@import 'bootstrap';

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the extension so that rollup knows its a sass file, don't forget the absolute path:

```
@import './bootstrap.scss';
```

Anyway, rollup sass plugins do not know to parse @import statements..for now.